# How to resize 2 embedded elements side by side together with the page size?

Tags: html, css, video

How do I embed these side by side and make them also resize with the page so that the video takes up about `70%` of the left side of the page and the chat takes up the other `30%`?

I also want them to resize as a group with the page so it always looks nice.

I am somewhat new to `HTML` and `CSS`, I appreciate any help from the pros.

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a class="active" href="watch.html">Watch</a>
  <a href="https://pushpay.com/g/southknoxvillechurchofgod" target="_blank">Give</a>
  <a href="events.html">Events</a>
</div>


<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://vimeo.com/event/1736206/embed" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe></div>

<iframe src="https://vimeo.com/event/1736206/chat/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the video and chat inside a flexbox container and customize the width for the video and chat separately. See the snippet below for your reference:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.video-container {
  width: 70%;
}

.chat-container {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Watch</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/watch.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="watch.html">Watch</a>
    <a href="https://pushpay.com/g/southknoxvillechurchofgod" target="_blank">Give</a>
    <a href="events.html">Events</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="video-container" style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://vimeo.com/event/1736206/embed" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe></div>
    <iframe class="chat-container" src="https://vimeo.com/event/1736206/chat/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```